# Inheritance and pointers

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, std, shared-ptr

I have code like this:

```
class Human
{
    protected:
        int age;
        std::string sex;    
    public: 
        virtual void speak() = 0;
};
class Child:public Human
{
    public:
        void speak(){std::cout << "I am Child\n";}
};
class Man:public Human
{
    public: 
        void speak(){std::cout << "I am Man\n";}
};
class Woman:public Human
{
    public: 
        void speak(){std::cout << "I am Woman\n";}
};
(don't know, std::shared_ptr<Human> maybe?) operator*(std::shared_ptr<Child> &b, int x)
{
    b->setAge(b->getAge()+x);
    if(b->getAge()>18 && b->getSex()=="Man")
    {
        return (i want b to become std::shared_ptr<Man>)
    }
    if(b->getAge()>18 && b->getSex()=="Woman")
    {
        return (here I want b to become std::shared_ptr<Woman>);
    }
    return;
}
int main(){
    auto x = std::make_shared<Child>;
    x*19;
}
```

I know it seems odd, but it's the simplest case i can think of, without having to write down all code i'm struggling with rn. Could someone explain, what type should overload be and how to change shared_ptr type, knowing they derive from same parent?

Comment: Are you asking how to define an operator overload for `shared_ptr` itself?

Comment: No matter what type you put there, this specific code won't build. How about a short paragraph describing what you wish to achieve?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth no, just want to know if its possible to change ptr type from b to c if they both derive from same class, and if its possible for method to return either ptr<B> or ptr <C>, depending on if statement

Comment: What I mean is, there's no way for `x*8` to compile - `x` is a `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth - `x` being a `shared_ptr` is not a hurdle in and of itself. Changing the operators parameter type from `B` to `shared_ptr<B>` is perfectly okay.

Comment: @StoryTeller - Agreed, just wanted to make sure we're on the same page as the OP on what they want to achieve here.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth - Oh, apologies then, I misunderstood you. Yes, it would be quite helpful if the OP would elaborate.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth, I've changed it so it's more readable

Comment: You have different classes for Man and Woman. Why not classes for Boy and Girl? Would make the whole thing simpler. But given both age *and* sex field, you don't need anything other than Human. Which is quite egalitarian.

Comment: @StoryTeller, it's for the project, it just needs to be this way. I have to have Child, Man, Woman, operator overload and if in the operator child becomes adult, it either becomes a man or a woman

Comment: You *need* to? What decides if you *need* to? This design is bad, and you are looking to have a language solution to a design problem. I'll tell you right now, the solution will not be from a language perspective. Improve the design.

Comment: I'm not allowed to change the design, it's a college homework

Comment: What is this design *for*? What are the requrements for the program?

Answer (score 0):

Objects cannot change type.  A `Child` object will always be a `Child` object.  What you can do is create a *new* object with the properties you want and return that:

```
std::shared_ptr<Human> operator*(std::shared_ptr<Human> b, int x)
{
    b->setAge(b->getAge()+x);
    if(b->getAge()>18 && b->getSex()=="Man") {
        return std::make_shared<Man>(b->getAge());
    } else if(b->getAge()>18 && b->getSex()=="Woman") {
        return std::make_shared<Woman>(b->getAge());
    } else {
       return b;
    }
}

int main(){
    std::shared_ptr<Human> x = std::make_shared<Child>;
    x = x*19;
}
```

This doesn't seem like a good design though.  A `Human`'s status as a child or adult would be better represented as an attribute of the object or by a function that checks if `age` is greater than 18.

Comment: I'm like 75% sure I tried this variation, and it didn't work, because x is, compiler-wise, std::shared_ptr<Human>, not std::shared_ptr<Child>, at least in c++11.

Comment: But now you can use this operator with
std::shared_ptr<Human> x = std::make_shared<Man> AND
std::shared_ptr<Human> x = std::make_shared<Woman>

Answer (score -2):

You cannot make the type `T<Derived>` inherit from `T<Base>` because C++ templates do not support covariance. To do so would be unsafe for certain types, such as mutable references to containers. (Imagine taking a reference to `std::vector<Cat>` as `std::vector<Animal>&` and pushing back a dog!)

(I would make this answer a comment, but I don't have comment abilities.)

Update:
You can write a non-template wrapper that handles heap data:

```
class Wrapper
{
public:
  Wrapper(Base* b) : raw(b) {}
  ~Wrapper() { delete raw; }
  Base& get() { return *base; }
private:
  Base* raw;
}
```

Of course, in your example, you use std::shared_ptr and not std::unique_ptr. You would have to handle reference counting instead of simply deleting the data in the destructor, but the technique of keeping an internal raw pointer still stands.

Update 2:

The above code could be used as is to provide a level of indirection, such that all classes that inherit from the base class may be held in the same type, without writing your own reference counter:

`std::shared_ptr<Wrapper>`

This solution may be seen as similar to doing `std::shared_ptr<Base*>`, except that the latter solution would leak memory.

Comment: You won't get the comment privilege if you abuse the answer mechanism for commenting.

Comment: I'm so sorry. I felt like my post was somewhat an answer but felt that it would be more appropriate as a comment. Should I delete it?

Comment: If you want to answer, by all means. But don't post what you intend as comment. So yes, improve this into an answer if you wish.

Comment: I added a better solution. Would you say that I improved my answer?